# Line numbering column colorization

Tags: minted

I have this simple MCVE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{minted}
\definecolor{bill}{RGB}{229,225,225}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[xleftmargin=20pt,framesep=2mm, bgcolor=bill, linenos]{html}
<select id="ddlViewBy">
  <option value="1">test1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">test2</option>
  <option value="3">test3</option>
</select>
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

The output is this:

[image]

As you can see, the `bgcolor` affect also the line numbering. I do not want that. So how to colorize the column corresponding to the line numbering in a different color?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to line numbering background to be white, simply reduce `xleftmargin`. If you want it to be another color you need to use `tcolorbox` or `mdframed`. The following is a tcolorbox version of a possible solution:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,skins}

\definecolor{bill}{RGB}{229,225,225}

\newtcblisting{mycode}{
    listing engine=minted,
    minted style=trac,
    minted language=html,
    minted options={fontsize=\small,linenos,numbersep=3mm},
    colback=bill,
    colframe=bill,
    listing only,
    left=5mm,
    enhanced,
    overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[red](frame.south west)rectangle([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{mycode}
<select id="ddlViewBy">
  <option value="1">test1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">test2</option>
  <option value="3">test3</option>
</select>
\end{mycode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The tcolorbox code is taken directly from the manual, section 15.5, with just few modifications. There you will find many insights for more possiblities of customization.

Comment: That was a great and clear explanation. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @Kabyle you're welcome : )